# OracleDB: Copy data from table in batches (several commits)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table TABLE_ORIG and want to copy data into an existing & empty TABLE_COPY. Normally I could just:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_COPY SELECT * FROM TABLE_ORIG ROWNUM <= 100000;
COMMIT;
```

But I would like to divide the whole copying process into batches and commit several times, possibly with sleeps inbetween. Here's pseudocode of what I'm trying to achieve (copy 100,000 rows but distribute them over 100 commits = 1000 rows copied per commit):

```
i=0;
for (i < 100):
    INSERT INTO TABLE_COPY SELECT * FROM TABLE_ORIG WHERE ROWNUM <= 1000;
    COMMIT;
    i++;
    SLEEP 5 seconds;
```

How can this be done in Oracle DB?

Comment: [DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.CREATE_CHUNKS_BY_ROWID](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.html#GUID-5CE1DA66-EF57-4D4A-8682-FF449B9EC78C) is what you are looking for. It does everything in background jobs

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do it this way?

Comment: If you actually want to move the data from one table to another in online mode then you may also try `alter table ... exchange [sub]partition ...`. It doesn't move the data around but exchanges segment references. Though it may create some management issues like different segment attributes and tablestpace.

Comment: The posted pseudocode seems to copy the same 1000 rows 100 times. Was the aim to copy al the rows, while minimising multiple full table scans of the same data? Are you licensed for partitioning?

Comment: It is important to explain precisely why you want to commit in batches instead of doing things the easy way. Unnecessarily breaking up the work is slower, consumes more cumulative resources, and requires more code. There are some exceptions to the rule though, for example if each row is 1GB in size and the database doesn't have enough UNDO.

Comment: @JonHeller The reason for me wanting it this way is strictly for testing purposes. The test needs the data to arrive in several batches with some delays inbetween.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Would it really copy the same 1000 rows? Either way, my original idea was to copy DIFFERENT 100,000 rows but distribute them over 100 batches (but each batch would have different rows copied, no duplicates)

Comment: @potato_programmer `SELECT * FROM TABLE_ORIG WHERE ROWNUM <= 1000` will take the first 1000 rows the query finds. If you run the same query again it will do exactly the same thing. I’m not sure why you expect it to do something different.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson I will admit that my notation was quite imprecise, I meant to write something like: COPY another 1000 rows that weren't copied yet. But either way, even if we stick to my original notation with 'ROWNUM <= 100',  are you sure it will always return the _same_ 1000 rows? I don't know if it's different in OracleDB, but I always had the impression that the 'LIMIT' clause does not have any defined rule for which rows will be picked.

Comment: @astentx But that runs it in parallel, no? I need to include sleeps inbetween the processed chunks.

Comment: @potato_programmer But you didn't specify this in the question. Add this processing into the PL/SQL block that will be executed.

Comment: @potato_programmer Try it. `select * from user_objects where rownum < 10`. Then run it again. It'll do the same thing it did before. It won't remember how many rows it returned last time, guess what you're trying to do and apply an offset to exclude previously returned rows and return the next 10, because it's not an AI powered superbrain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin with, it is important to understand your reasons for wanting to do this weird data copying.
It would be wrong to copy large amounts of data by making intermediate transactions using the cursor. It is also worth considering possible changes to the source and target tables made during the copying process by other sessions.

If we are copying data in multiple transactions, it is important to avoid copying already copied data again with each subsequent request. This can be achieved in different ways:

1. divide the source data into ranges based on surrogate key values
2. divide the initial data into ranges by ROWID values
3. check for a copy in the target table for each source row to be copied.

My example uses the latter method. There are no indexes needed for optimization.

```sql
create table TABLE_ORIG as 
  select object_id, owner, object_name, object_type 
    from all_objects
/
Create table TABLE_COPY as select * from TABLE_ORIG where 1=0
/
declare
  p_chunk_size pls_integer := 10000;
  p_sleep_delay number := 1;
begin
  loop
    insert into TABLE_COPY 
      select * from TABLE_ORIG o 
        where not exists (
          select null from TABLE_COPY c2
            where c2.object_id = o.object_id
        )
        and rownum<=p_chunk_size;
     if sql%rowcount = 0 then
       exit;
     end if;
     dbms_output.put_line(sql%rowcount);
     commit;
     dbms_session.sleep(p_sleep_delay);
  end loop;
  commit; -- close last empty transaction
end;
/
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/lvEfxOYL)

Comment: Interesting, thanks! How would this solution compare to opening a cursor on a SELECT of all data from TABLE_ORIG?

Comment: Committing over open cursor - is a poor idea. See [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5757640/1855313) about this or search about ORA-01555 error.